# deleting files in javascript

Tags: javascript

is it possible to delete a file(s) inside the directory by just using javascript ?. what I currently have is, an index.php which displays the name of the files in the same directory and and a checkbox to each file name and at the bottom is a delete button. what I want to happen is, delete all the selected checkboxes once the delete button is clicked. I am not using mysql here, just a plain php file that displays the names. can someone show me how to delete the selected files using javascript ?

Comment: Imagine the fun if JavaScript was able to do this natively and you'd visit a site that does a `rm -rf /' on your machine :-D. Actually, you *can* access the filesystem in JavaScript in **browser-specific** ways (such as through an ActiveX object in Internet Explorer).

Comment: @stakx I wouldn't call ActiveX a *JavaScript* browser-specific way...

Comment: @deceze: Why not? The code itself will still be written in JavaScript (or EcmaScript, if you like), BUT it'll be browser-specific. The EcmaScript standard defines certain standard objects (such as `Date` or `Math`), others such as `window` or `location` are part of the *de facto* Browser Object Model standard, and yet others -- such as the availability of certain ActiveX components -- are even more browser-specific. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @stakx But you would need to write the ActiveX component in something other than Javascript, so I'd rather call it a browser-specific way that is exploitable by Javascript. A matter of POV I guess. :)

Comment: @deceze: I didn't claim, nor intend to say, that ActiveX components must themselves be written in JavaScript (they aren't, of course). But you are perhaps correct in that my comment may be misleading to someone who doesn't know about ActiveX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not delete files with javascript for **security reasons**. Bad guys can delete files of your stytem :( However, you can do so with the combination of server-side language such as PHP, ASP.NET, etc using what is know as **[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)**.

**Note:** Javascript is moving to adding/becoming the server-side language options. **[Node JS](http://nodejs.org/)** is an example of that.

**Update Based On Comment:**

You can delete files something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('a.delete').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
       url:'delete.php',
       data:'id/name here',
       method:'GET',
       success:function(response){
        if (response === 'deleted')
        {
           alert('Deleted !!');
        }
       }
      });
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
   if (isset($_GET['id/name here']))
   {
     if (unlink('your_folder_path' . $_GET['id/name here']))
     {
       echo 'Deleted';
     }
   }
```

Comment: can you show me an example of that ajax thingy based on my problem's description ?

Comment: thank you very much for the example sir, i was thinking of using manual ajax, but it's hard for me LOL, jquery is the best.

Comment: @sasori: You should take this *as an example only*! Without additional security checks, this can get very dangerous, when the submitted file name is something like `../../etc/passwords` (assumed the server would have write permissions, but still...).

Answer (score 4):

You can use AJAX,and delete files using PHP on server.
You can't manipulate with files in pure javascript.

Comment: can you show me an example of that ajax thingy based on my problem's description ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the file deletion function in PHP based on the built-in unlink() function. Be careful here!! for example, you should read the list of file names and calculate an ID for each of them, and your delete function would accept IDs and NOT the real filename(s).

Then, when you send the file list to the browser, it includes the generated IDs as hidden fields or object attributes, etc. From JavaScript, you can use an HTTP request to send a list of file IDs to be deleted, based on the checkboxes. Your PHP script would call your delete function for the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript for that but a HTML `form` which sends the filenames to a PHP script on the server which deletes the files. See [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Answer (score 0):

In this, use ajax function or otherwise by javascript in onclick function provide the submit action and refresh the whole page.