# How to delete files via javascript

Tags: javascript, ftp

I need to delete files via native javascript without ajax & php, how I can do It?

I havn't seen this proposition at any other websites, so I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: JavaScript has no native concept of a file. If you want to work with a file system, then you'll need to run the JS in a host environment (such as Node.js) that provides a file system API. If you want to delete a file on a server from a web browser without setting up the server explicitly then ask yourself, if that was possible, why aren't most websites regularly deleted by trolls?

Comment: Duplicate question.
check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450433/how-to-delete-a-file-with-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450433/how-to-delete-a-file-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript, it can't be done. Using an AJAX call to a server side script that deletes the file would work though

btw are you want to hack something?.. just curious

[How to delete a file with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450433/how-to-delete-a-file-with-javascript)

Comment: No I don't need to hack someone just I argued with a friend that ))